# More efficient way of symmetrizing a square matrix in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I have an "almost symmetric" matrix, which I wish to symmetrize in MATLAB. For example, I wish to symmetrize

```
>> A = [0 0 1; 2 0 3; 0 3 0]

A =

     0     0     1
     2     0     3
     0     3     0
```

into

```
>> B

B =

     0     2     1
     2     0     3
     1     3     0
```

Safe assumptions are that diagonal entries of `A` are all zero and that "the bits to change" are always `0`. E.g., I changed `A(1, 2)` and `A(3, 1)` in the above example, and original values at both locations were `0`.

---

My best attempt based on [@Photon's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38418587/more-efficient-way-of-symmetrizing-a-square-matrix-in-matlab/38418928?noredirect=1#comment64243993_38418587) (Thanks Photon!) is

```
>> C = -0.5*(A.'.*A~=0)+1;
>> B = (A+A.').*C

B =

     0     2     1
     2     0     3
     1     3     0
```

---

Is there a better (more efficient or faster) way of achieving this?

Comment: Not exactly what you wanted, but perhaps better:  B=0.5*(A+A')

Comment: `B = A + A'.*(A=0)` should only add the values of `A'` that are 0 in `A`.

Comment: @arcadeprecinct I think you meant `A==0`. +1, simper than mine!

Comment: @SibbsGambling Oh of course `A==0`! Confused languages -.-

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about

```
B = max( A, A.' );
```

Assuming all entries of `A` are non-negative.

Comment: thanks!; didn't know `max` can pick up the biggest value at each element!